# How to gives a black border to TreeItem SWT?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, draw2d

I have created Tree with more than 1 column using TreeColumn. Right now what I want to achieve is to create border cell for the cell item in Tree. Here is my implementation now:
[image]

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean tree.setLinesVisible(true); ?

Comment: yah, that's exactly what I want. Thanks :)